# Setting of y axis in a plot

Tags: r

I have a very simple problem regarding plot settings.

I would like to have ticks (and labels on these ticks) on the y axis in a special way. For instance from 3 to 9, by one unit.

This is the code:

```
windows()         
par(yaxp = c(3, 9, 7))
plot(1:10)
```

But it does not work. And I really do not understand why?
I also tried playing around with arguments from par() such as tck, tcl, yaxs, yaxt, yaxp and the function axis(). Which lead for example among others to the following codes:

```
windows()
par(yaxt = "n", yaxp = c(3, 9, 7))
plot(1:10)
```

or

```
windows()
par(yaxt = "n")
plot(1:10)
axis(2, at = c(3, 4, 5))
```

Unfortunately, I failed in every case...
Any ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me?

```
plot(1:10, yaxp = c(3, 9, 6))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You've received some good solutions to your immediate problem, but I thought I'd answer the "Why?" portion. R's documentation in this instance is correct, but perhaps not as transparent as it could be.

If you examine the section of `?par` describing `xaxp`, you'll find:

> This parameter is reset when a user coordinate system is set up, for
>   example by starting a new page or by calling plot.window or setting
>   par("usr"): n is taken from par("lab").

Under `yaxp`, the same warning is not given, but instead it says simple 'See `xaxp`'. There is no similar warning for the `usr` parameter in `?par`, but the same is probably the case, since if we look up `?plot.window` we see:

> A side-effect of the call is to set up the usr, xaxp and yaxp

So what's happening is that a call to `plot` eventually leads to calling `plot.window`, a side effect of which is to actually *reset* the settings for `usr`, `xaxp` and `yaxp`. Unless, of course, you have passed those arguments directly to a higher level function like `plot` that in turn hands them off down the line to `plot.window`.

Personally, I think this deserves mention in the Details section of `?par` along with the list of parameters that can *only* be set by using `par()` rather than passing them to high level plotting functions.

Comment: Hi joran, that's a really interessting information! But If I understood correctly what you found out, it does NERVER make sense to use one of the arguments usr, xaxp and yaxp in par, because they will be resetted from the polt function. Or can you think of a case, where it does make sense??

Answer (score 6):

I normally solve this by setting `axes = FALSE` in the call to plot() and then use `axis()` to draw the individual axes.

```
# no call to par() needed
plot(c(1:10), axes = FALSE)
axis(1)                     # x-Axis
ticks <- seq(3, 9, 1)       # sequence for ticks and labels
axis(2, at = ticks,         # y-Axis
    labels = ticks)
box()                       # and a box around the plot
```